# Explain C++ Mutability through Indirection example

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation

In C++ Programming Language, 4th edition, section 16.2.9.4 "Mutability through Indirection" has a sketch of an example of using indirection instead of the `mutable` keyword for lazy evaluation.

```
struct cache {
    bool valid;
    string rep;
};
 
class Date {
public:
    // ...
    string string_rep() const;
private:
    cache * c;    // initialize in constructor
    void compute_cache_value() const;
    // ...
};
 
string Date::string_rep() const {
    if (!c->valid) {
        compute_cache_value();
        c->valid = true;
    }
    return c->rep;
}
```

[Full runnable example](http://ideone.com/mTYBVb).

There isn't a lot of explanation:

> Declaring a member `mutable` is most appropriate when only a small part of a representation of small object is allowed to change. More complicated cases are often better handled by placing the changing data in a separate object and accessing it directly.

I'm am looking for a more complete explanation. In particular,

- What is the smallness constraint? Is it a small amount of memory or a small amount of logic?
- Doesn't initializing `c` in the constructor defeat (to a nontrivial degree) the laziness? That is, it does work you many never need.
- Why is `c` a naked pointer instead of something like `unique_ptr`? The previous chapters went to a bit of effort to demonstrate exception safety and RAII.
- Why not just have a `mutable cache c` member if you're going to allocate and initialize `c` in the constructor anyway?

In other words, is this a real pattern or a contrived example to demonstrate indirection versus const-ness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "smallness constraint" isn´t a real constraint, just a hint how to write the code (and it has not much to do with used memory). If you have a class with 30 members, and 20 out of them are mutable, it could make more sense to separate it into two classes (one for the mutable part and one for the rest).

Why it´s not a smart pointer: Don´t know, but probably a too tired book author :p

Why it´s a pointer at all: You´re right, it´s not necessary. Making a mutable cache object without any pointer will work too, and if nothing pointer-like is needed otherwise (like getting an existing object from outside), the pointer only adds another possibility for making bugs.

Comment: To the last phrase: `mutable` could lead to serious and nasty bugs too. With `mutable`, you basically lie to compiler and lie to user. We all know how to debug null pointers or memory leaks, but mutability issues are still very tricky, especially in concurrent code. So we could not say that it is better for any purpose than an indirection solution.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Warning: neither of following text has any practical value for battlefield programmers, rather than for programmers-philosophers or just plain philosophers. Also, I'm a big fan of Bjarne Stroustrup and my opinion might be biased. Unfortunately, StackOverflow format is not fit for book discussions.</sup>

<sup>Also, we are discussing awkward issues about constness-mutability where we should lie to compiler and to class user. And there are no single right opinion. I'm ready to be commented and downvoted ;)</sup>

In short:

- you probably didn't understand right what lazy initialization means exactly (probably because the term is not chosen correctly in the book) <sup>As with RAII, we know that Bjarne is known to be bad at picking terminology ;)</sup>
- there are few decisions that have to be made when writing a book about programming. So some of the questions boil down to "How to write a book?" rather than "How to write production code?".

In long:

1. > What is the smallness constraint? Is it a small amount of memory or a
   >   small amount of logic?

   I'll quote Bjarne again:

   > Declaring a member mutable is **most appropriate** when only **a small part of a representation** of small object is allowed to change

   I think he meant "small number of data members" here. Refactoring by grouping data members into separate class is a good advice in general. What's the ratio between  "appropriate" and "small"? You decide it for yourself (given a real problem, a profiler tool and constraints on memory/speed/battery_life/money/client_happiness etc.)
2. > Doesn't initializing c in the constructor defeat (to a nontrivial degree) the laziness? That is, it does work you many never need.

   Well, by lazy initialization we mean *non-calculating* proper string value (i.e. `compute_cache_value()`) each time user ask for a string, but only when really needed. Not an initialization with empty string, right? <sup>(`std::string` initializes to empty string on construction anyway)</sup>

   There is no any constructors in Bjarne's code in chapters 16.2.9.3 and 16.2.9.4! And you don't calculate string in a constructor in your code too, but initialize it with an empty string literal. All calculations are delayed until last moment. So, lazy initialization works perfectly for me here.

   <sup>As further <strike>premature</strike> optimization, if you want real lazy *initialization*, you could probably left `cache*` pointer uninitialized in the constructor, and allocate on first `Date::string_rep()` call. This will safe bunch of heap if your cache is big and if user never need it. And this way you wrap calculations in `cache` constructor which renders lazy evaluation to really lazy initialization</sup>
3. > Why is c a naked pointer instead of something like unique_ptr? The
   >   previous chapters went to a bit of effort to demonstrate exception
   >   safety and RAII.

   In "C++ Programming Language, 4th edition" smart pointers are introduced in chapter 17, and we are talking about chapter 16. Also, it doesn't really matter to describe the mutability and brings no advantages as long as you manage to `delete` in destructor. Another thing is that author would have explained in this chapter why you can mutate a resource owned by `smart_ptr cache` having only constant `smart_ptr` object inside `const` method, which will pull in describing operator overloading <sup>(and most high-level <strike>Java and Python</strike> programers would throw away the book at that place ;) ).</sup>

   <sup>Apart of this, that's a hard question in general. First of all, Books by Bjarne Stroustrup are considered mostly as teaching materials or guides. So, when teaching newcomers, should we jump in to smart pointers or to teach raw pointers first? Should we instantly use Standard library or left it for the last chapters? C++14 from the beginning or "C+" first? Who knows? There is also a problem known as "over-usage of smart pointers", notably `shared_ptr`.</sup>
4. > Why not just have a mutable cache c member if you're going to allocate  and initialize c in the constructor anyway?

   That's what described in 16.2.9.3, right?

   <strike>And adding a level of indirection here is the alternative solution (showing "there is no universal solutions for all purposes") and demonstration of this amazing quote:</strike>

   > All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, except for the problem of too many layers of indirection.
   >   – David J. Wheeler

   No. As user *xan* clarified, 16.9.3 is about multiple mutable members, whereas a single `mutable` `struct` would provide some separation of concerns.

Hope you enjoy the reading!

Comment: FYI, unique_ptr is introduced in 5.2.1. And 16.9.3 is about multiple mutable members, whereas a single mutable struct would provide some separation of concerns, a la "Refactoring by grouping data members into separate class is a good advice in general."

Comment: @xan So, basically you are asking why he didn't mention this variant with `mutable cache` in this book? Probably, it's because it's not different from 16.9.3. You just group up `bool` and `string`. But solution with a pointer is completely different.

Comment: I'm generally wondering if the example is more of a recommended technique or an illustration of const pointer behavior. The latter is seeming more likely.

Comment: Oh I see. I forgot your last question. Theese examples are very rare. Both of it have very little practical purpose in my opinion. In multithreaded world we have very little place for such a hacks. But still you should know that it exist, have it in your toolbox and know how to use it. Also, analysis of such things brings better understanding of language itself, class design, pointers, performance optimization possibilities etc. So yes, it is mostly an illustration.